# Transposing when finding hypotenuse

Tags: trigonometry

Background: I have just about high school knowledge of math, I am sorry if this is a stupid question.

In school, we learned that when transposing, this:

`y = x * 3`

would become

`x = y / 3`

I was reading up on trigonometry, and as I was reading the following:

> If we look at the general definition -
>
> [image]
>
> we see that there are three variables: the measure of the angle x, and
>   the lengths of the two sides (Opposite and Hypotenuse). So if we have
>   any two of them, we can find the third.
>
> In the figure above, click 'reset'. Imagine we didn't know the length
>   of the hypotenuse H. We know that the sine of A (60°) is the opposite
>   side (26) divided by H.
>
> [image]
>
> From our calculator we find that sin60 is 0.866, so we can write
>
> [image]
>
> Transposing:
>
> [image]
>
> which comes out to 30.02

(From http://www.mathopenref.com/sine.html)

As per the rules of transposition (that I probably got wrong), isn't it supposed to read

`H = 26 * 0.866`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first divide both sides by $H$: $$0.866=\frac{26}{H},$$
then we divide by $0,886$ on both sides: $$0.886H=26,$$
We receive this result: $$H=\frac{26}{0.866}.$$

Thus, the answer is $30.06.$

Answer (score 0):

Transpose means to isolate the variable. In the problem given you are trying to isolate the $H$ variable. Using algebra:

our problem:
$$0.866 = \frac{26}H  $$

$$H\cdot 0.866 = \frac{26}H \cdot H$$

$$0.866H = 26$$

$$\frac{0.866H}{0.866} = \frac{26}{0.866}$$

$H = 30.02$ is the correct answer not $30.06$.

Multiplying both sides by $H$ cancels the $H$ in the quotient.
Dividing both sides by the coefficient of $H$ cancels the $0.866$ in the product.